# Python Flask could not add new user instead of it display else part message

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I'm adding new user from python flask using mysql db =>table name user, below code are using for add user in python flask

```
# New user
@app.route("/addUser", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def addUser():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            Name = request.form["Name"]
            Age = request.form["Age"]
            City = request.form["City"]
            data = (Name, Age, City)
            con = mysql.connection.cursor()
            sql = "insert into user(Name, Age, City) Values(%S,%S,%S)"
            mysql.execute(sql, data)
            mysql.connection.commit()
            con.close()
            flash("Add New User Detail successfully")
            print("addUser")
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            return 'Error while adding user'
```

Comment: please check if GET has your vdata, also you can use the developer tools from your browser to debug

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but not all database connectors will accept uppercase `%S` as a placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

If you display else part message - than you do not use POST method on client side.